# What's wrong with this table formatting for IE 8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

This table (example below) is generated by XML files and an XSL.

When the XML is loaded locally, it works fine (from 127.0.0.1):

[image]

When it is loaded from another computer on the LAN or from a networked drive, this happens:

[image]

I don't know why the positions of the headers change. It is the doubled borders on the table that are really irritating me. After Googling for 48 hours straight I haven't been able to find a solution that works. I need help!

Here is the table HTML:

```html
<TABLE class=tablePrimaire>
    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TH rowSpan=2 scope=col>Période comptable</TH>
            <TH colSpan=6 scope=col>Informations Clé Comptable</TH>
            <TH colSpan=6 scope=col>Informations Mouvement Comptable</TH>
            <TH colSpan=3 scope=col>Informations Compte Comptable</TH>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TH scope=col>Code géographique</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Affectation</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Type garant</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Ligne ER</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Matricule</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Qui</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Montant non contrevalorisé</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Montant contrevalorisé</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Date de signature</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Date de mise en vigueur</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Devise d'enregistrement</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Origine</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Numéro de compte comptable</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Libellé numéro de compte comptable</TH>
            <TH scope=col>Sens</TH>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD rowSpan=4>ll_pec193</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>code_geo237</TD>
            <TD>affect238</TD>
            <TD>type_garant239</TD>
            <TD>ligne_er240</TD>
            <TD>matricule241</TD>
            <TD>qui242</TD>
            <TD>mnt_nn_ctrvalo84</TD>
            <TD>mnt_ctrvalo83</TD>
            <TD>date_sign85</TD>
            <TD>date_mis_vig86</TD>
            <TD>code_devise89</TD>
            <TD>origine89</TD>
            <TD>num_cpt_cmpt235</TD>
            <TD>ll_cmpt30</TD>
            <TD>sens_cpt32</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>code_geo246</TD>
            <TD>affect247</TD>
            <TD>type_garant248</TD>
            <TD>ligne_er249</TD>
            <TD>matricule250</TD>
            <TD>qui251</TD>
            <TD>mnt_nn_ctrvalo85</TD>
            <TD>mnt_ctrvalo84</TD>
            <TD>date_sign86</TD>
            <TD>date_mis_vig87</TD>
            <TD>code_devise90</TD>
            <TD>origine90</TD>
            <TD>num_cpt_cmpt236</TD>
            <TD>ll_cmpt40</TD>
            <TD>sens_cpt42</TD>
        </TR>
            <TR>
                <TD>code_geo266</TD>
                <TD>affect267</TD>
                <TD>type_garant268</TD>
                <TD>ligne_er269</TD>
                <TD>matricule260</TD>
                <TD>qui261</TD>
                <TD>mnt_nn_ctrvalo94</TD>
                <TD>mnt_ctrvalo93</TD>
                <TD>date_sign95</TD>
                <TD>date_mis_vig96</TD>
                <TD>code_devise99</TD>
                <TD>origine91</TD>
                <TD>num_cpt_cmpt237</TD>
                <TD>ll_cmpt50</TD>
                <TD>sens_cpt52</TD>
            </TR>
    </TBODY>
    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD rowSpan=2>ll_pec200</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD>mnt_nn_ctrvalo198</TD>
            <TD>mnt_ctrvalo112</TD>
            <TD>date_sign95</TD>
            <TD>date_mis_vig96</TD>
            <TD>code_devise99</TD>
            <TD>origine100</TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD></TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD rowSpan=2>ll_pec198</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>code_geo245</TD>
            <TD>affect246</TD>
            <TD>type_garant247</TD>
            <TD>ligne_er248</TD>
            <TD>matricule249</TD>
            <TD>qui250</TD>
            <TD>mnt_nn_ctrvalo198</TD>
            <TD>mnt_ctrvalo93</TD>
            <TD>date_sign95</TD>
            <TD>date_mis_vig96</TD>
            <TD>code_devise99</TD>
            <TD>origine100</TD>
            <TD>num_cpt_cmpt244</TD>
            <TD>ll_cmpt40</TD>
            <TD>sens_cpt42</TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
.tablePrimaire
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.tablePrimaire th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    height: 30px;  
    background-color: #8c8b83;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.tablePrimaire td
{
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 17px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

tbody
{
    background: #f9f4e9;
}

tbody:nth-child(odd)
{
    background: #eee0c1;
}

tbody:hover td[rowspan], tr:hover td
{
    background: #d0e4f2; 
}
```

I'm looking forward to your suggestions!

I should mention that it works fine in Firefox, locally or not.

*This is the first real time I'm playing around with HTML and CSS so I'm really sorry for any obvious faults and faux-pas.*

Comment: How about remove all css code, then check it again.It may help you find out some extra css setting which may cause ur issue.

Comment: I've already done that to no avail. This image: http://snag.gy/QZUKC.jpg results from the code below:

`.tablePrimaire
{
border: 1px solid black;
}

.tablePrimaire td
{
border: 1px solid black;
}`

You can see the alignement differences and how the double border arises. Again, this does not happen when accessed locally.

Comment: Are you specifying a doctype? If so, what is it?

Comment: The output line in the XSL is as follows:

`<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//XSD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd"/>`

Comment: Here's the image above, but locally: http://snag.gy/e6n3K.jpg

Same XML, same CSS on the table (the line above). This one works when the rest of the styling is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're being caught out by IE's compatibility behaviour. If you are on a domain, by default, any servers on your local network (on the domain or not) are treated as the Intranet Zone: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2005/12/07/501075.aspx

And in the Intranet Zone, by default, all pages select "Emulate IE7 'standards'" mode: http://www.nathanfox.net/blog/63/Internet-Explorer-8-compatibility-view-and-the-local-intranet-zone

To get around this, use the X-UA-Compatible HTTP header, or as a `<meta>` tag (though it does not validate in the W3C validator). See [Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#ie8modes) for details of IE 8's full behaviour.

Comment: You are an amazing person. Thank you! And curse IE.

Comment: All I had to do was add this to the `<head>` tag:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>`

Comment: I also highly recommend this one-ligner to bring IE up to speed: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `>` on line 25.  It should read `</TR>` instead of `</TR`.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake on here, it's not in the actual code. Corrected.